# Rest amid daily work period

Tags: word-usage

to say "have a rest in the middle of work", can I say 'rest amid my daily work period"? Does 'amid' only describe "surrounded by", like in, "rest amid chaos", or can it mean "a time-point within a certain period"? Thank you.

Comment: a siesta! i plan on one today around 2 pm!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary definitions are ambiguous about this, but I can't remember ever hearing "amid" with a time period.

At the workplace specifically, some common ways of phrasing it are: "take a break," "go on break," or "step out."  ("Go on break" is typically used with jobs paid by the hour, where your break is a pre-set duration).